# asp.net nHibernate selecting data from a View mapped

Tags: asp.net, nhibernate, nhibernate-mapping, sybase

I have two tables and one view:

```
TABLE "Table_1" (
    "Id" INTEGER NOT NULL DEFAULT AUTOINCREMENT,
    "Field_1" VARCHAR(11) NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY ( "Id" ASC )
) IN "system";

TABLE "Table_2" (
    "Table_1_Id" INTEGER NOT NULL,  //// (THIS FIELD HAVE A FOREIGN KEY WITH TABLE "Table_1" FIELD "Id")
    "Field_2" VARCHAR(11) NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY ( "Table_1_Id" ASC )
) IN "system";

VIEW "vwView_1"()
AS
select 
    Id, 
    Field_1, 
    Field_2 
from Table_1 key join Table_2
```

This is the View map:

```
...
Table("vwView_1");
Mutable(false);
Id(x => x.Id);
Property(x => x.Field_1);
Property(x => x.Field_2);
...
```

This is the View data in the database:

```
Id  Field_1  Field_2
1   Green    Blue
1   Green    Red
2   Black    White
3   Orange   Blue
6   Red      Orange
6   Red      Green
```

When I get the data with nHibernate, I got this data:

```
Id  Field_1  Field_2
1   Green    Blue
1   Green    Blue
2   Black    White
3   Orange   Blue
6   Red      Orange
6   Red      Orange
```

I think that the problem is in View map, but I can't find a way to resolve this :(

Somebody have an idea to resolve?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have the Id column mapped as the Identifier field, so NHibernate's first level cache doesn't bother to re-read rows that it has already cached. That's why all the values with the same Id value have the same values for Field_1 and Field_2.

Maybe you can add a ROW_NUMBER() field in your view and map that as the identifier.

Comment: Thanks Tuan, I'll try this too. After I'll back here and post the result.

Answer (score 2):

Your view is not returning a `unique ID` therefore when NHibernate sees the duplicate Id it already thinks that the row is hydrated as it is in the first level cache. Therefore it just returns the same duplicated row, which is why you are seeing the behaviour `1, Green, Blue` and `1, Green, Blue`

You have two options:-

1. in your view return a unique id which is the unique Id in table 2 although that judging by your schema that does not look possible
2. You need to override `equals` and `GetHashCode` in your view map class, see this [blog](http://devlicio.us/blogs/anne_epstein/archive/2009/11/20/nhibernate-and-composite-keys.aspx) for more info.

Comment: Thanks Rippo, I'll try the first option :) After I'll back here and post the result.

Comment: If you think about it you have a composite key in your view, overrides is your best friend here :) And its not to scary honest! :)

Comment: I added a column in the view (how Tuan says) and I changed mapping Id, and now works. Thanks. +1 for answare.

Comment: Urm not meaning to sound bitter, but isn't my point one the same as Tuans answer, plus I did answer a few minutes before Tuan! Oh well